# iPad - Issue using CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa, gps

I need to find my current location using the GPS without internet and show on Google Maps.

**On iPhone**

All ok and show the location.

**On iPad**

I use the `CLLocationManager` as `delegate`. Yet it returns me the following error on method `didFailWithError:(NSError *)error`:

Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"

Creation CLLocationManager code:

```
locationManager                 = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
locationManager.delegate        = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter  = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

PS: I need to find the current location without any internet connection. iPad show indicator localization on status bar. (With internet connection all ok and show location). The iPad is 4th generation with iOS 7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wifi only model iPad does not have a GPS receiver. It is only capable of receiving location data through wifi data. You need a wifi + cellular iPad to accomplish location without wifi.

Note, this also applies to iPod touch models. As a general rule for iOS devices, if it does not have a cell receiver, it must use wifi for GPS.

Comment: I did not really know this. Thank you so much.